# Raise Redis cluster authorization

Tags: redis, cluster-computing

I can raise a cluster of 3 masters and 3 slaves (using `redis-trib` or without it), but without any security, who knows how to raise redis cluster password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add 'requirepass ' to redis.conf to enable authentication.

Comment: What if I start each node with a parameter `--requirepass=mypass`?

(I did so, but now does not work redis-trib, for obvious reasons, and one of the master node can not I add more nodes by
`redis-cli CLUSTER MEET xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx 6379`)